# Print preview will not print text area exactly as in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, printing, textarea

This is what my `textarea` looks like at my Chrome browser.

[image]

but for some strange reason, my print preview does not appear like in the browser:

[image]

Why is the print preview text area not fully extend as shown in my browser? Here is my code that will extend textarea height based on content:

```
var resize = document.getElementById('description')

resize.style.overflow = 'hidden';
resize.style.height = 0;
resize.style.height = resize.scrollHeight + 'px';
console.log("resize", resize.scrollHeight + 'px')                            
window.print();
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should change your margin property in print setup. However A4 paper is 21cm so I wouldn't expect it to look like in your webbrowser

Comment: hidden overflow break ur page :)

Comment: if you want to change margin's in chrome print setup, go to more options then from list choose custom marigins and then fell free to adjust them. http://superuser.com/questions/457861/how-to-change-the-google-chrome-default-print-margins

Comment: I extend the margin outward to 0;. Unfortunately text area did not continue to next page.